# Jenkins. Use a shared library on the options phase

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I have created a shared library in jenkins with a listener that gets triggered each time the pipelines reads a FlowNode so I can run groovy code before and after each stage, step, etc...

I'm able to call the shared library in a step phase like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('prepare') { 
            steps{
                prepareStepsWrapper()
            }
        }
        stage('step1') { 
            steps {
                echo 'step1'
            }
        }
        stage('step2') { 
            steps {
                echo 'step2'
            }
        }
        stage('step3') { 
            steps {
                echo 'step3'
                // fail on purpose
                sh 'notfoundexecutablelol'
            }
        }
        stage('step4') { 
            steps {
                echo 'step4'
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            println env.getEnvironment()
        }
    }
}
```

And works pretty great!

With this approach the 'prepare' stage needs to be filtered out so I've switched to the options directive:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        prepareStepsWrapper()
    }
    stages {
        stage('step1') { 
            steps {
                echo 'step1'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But the pipeline fails with

> WorkflowScript: 4: Invalid option type "prepareStepsWrapper"

**tl;dr; How can I load a shared library within the options directive?**

Answer (score 1):

What does the option-stage do?

> The options directive allows configuring Pipeline-specific options
>   from within the Pipeline itself.

You can't call the shared-library in the `options-stage`. This stage should not be used for execute any logic, rather it sets configurations for the pipeline.  All availables options and the documentation can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options).

You could try to create a stage that simply calls your `prepareStepsWrapper()` and use [locks](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/) to avoid that other stages are executed before this stage.

Comment: In this case my shared library sets configuration for the pipeline, for instance its sets the configuration per each stage and also calls other options directives like timestamps or gitlabConnection.

Comment: Ah ok. Why do you put these options into a shared-library? You could also put them directly into the options-stage.

Comment: I have multiple pipeline projects with multiple Jenkinsfile each. There are like 5 different types and the idea is to be able to configure a pipeline with just a few calls on the aspects that compose each, like ie: enableProdEnvironment(), enableFineTimeTrack(), etc...

Comment: This makes sense but sadly I am not sure if it will work this way. Maybe think about giving each pipeline its own options-stage.